# how to permanently hide search icon when input is not empty only with css

Tags: html, css

I am applying search icon in every input textbox.
My problem comes with icon when there is some value in it.

you can see it here-

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7k2B/)

When I am doing focus in, then the search icon goes hidden, But how do I manage so it keeps hiding this icon when there is some value in it?

**css-**

```
.input-search {
    background:url('http://www.aljanaedu.com/Limitless/images/icons/14x14/search.png') no-repeat left 10px center;
}
    .input-search:focus {
        background-image:none;
    }
```

I could do It with jQuery easily, but is there any way of doing it with CSS only?

Answer (score 2):

I've updated your fiddle, you can try it out!
http://jsfiddle.net/X7k2B/6/

HTML:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    id="myInput" 
    placeholder="Some Fallback Text" >
```

CSS:

```
#myInput::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
  text-indent: -9999px;
   background:url('http://www.aljanaedu.com/Limitless/images/icons/14x14/search.png') no-repeat left 10px center;
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
#myInput::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: transparent;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/123x17&text=PlaceholderImage");
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
#myInput:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: transparent;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/123x17&text=PlaceholderImage");
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
#myInput:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10- */
  color: transparent;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/123x17&text=PlaceholderImage");
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: Making it placeholder is a good idea, But I guess cross browsing issue would hurt me

Comment: I believe HTML5 is very well supported as of this point, is this just incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good option

```
<style>
#foo:valid { outline: solid blue 2px; }
#foo:invalid { outline: solid red 2px; }
</style>
<input id=foo required>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s6G57/

So in your case it would look like this

```
<style>
.input-search:invalid {
    background:url('http://www.aljanaedu.com/Limitless/images/icons/14x14/search.png') no-repeat left 10px center;
}
.input-search:valid {
    background: #fff;
}
</style>
```

then just add required to your input

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. I think the attribute selector works from the value of the element's `value` attribute, rather than from the the value of the textfield in the DOM. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X7k2B/3/

Comment: Found another solution

Comment: @LagMaster, hehe clever !